# Indicate a Last_Name + First_Name has one record with specific value

Tags: sql

In this code, the results are: In our case, I would like to know which row does not have a 1 in the column is_primary_mo, in our case TANNE I would want a column 'NP' as BANTT has a record with 1.

```
last_name   First_Name is_primary_mo    street_address_1
8712    BANTT   1   Center 1
8712    BANTT   0   Center A
8713   TANNE    0   Center 2
8713   TANNE    0   Center 5
```

```
select b.last_name, b.first_name, a.is_primary_mo, a.street_address_1 
from staff_office_demographics_byprimary_view a
inner join staff_view b
  on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
order by b.last_name, b.last_name
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired resulting output?

Answer (score 0):

Your exact desired result is unclear to me but I hope the below gets you going in the right direction:

Get firstname and lastname where there is at least one record with is_primary_mo = 1 in staff_office_demographics_byprimary_view:

```
select b.last_name, b.first_name
from staff_office_demographics_byprimary_view a
inner join staff_view b
  on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
group by b.last_name, b.first_name
having SUM(a.is_primary_mo) > 0 
order by b.last_name, b.last_name
```

Get firstname and lastname where there is exactly one record with is_primary_mo = 1 in staff_office_demographics_byprimary_view:

```
select b.last_name, b.first_name
from staff_office_demographics_byprimary_view a
inner join staff_view b
  on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
group by b.last_name, b.first_name
having SUM(a.is_primary_mo) = 1 
order by b.last_name, b.last_name
```

Get firstname and lastname where there is no record with is_primary_mo = 1 in staff_office_demographics_byprimary_view:

```
select b.last_name, b.first_name
from staff_office_demographics_byprimary_view a
inner join staff_view b
  on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
group by b.last_name, b.first_name
having SUM(a.is_primary_mo) = 0 
order by b.last_name, b.last_name
```